# How to add my Dialog Flow's access token correcly in environment folder in Angular cli

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-cli, dialogflow-es

I am developing a bot with angular cli and using dialog flow's API. The problem is that I am getting these error logs when I debug via Chrome:

`ApiAiClientConfigurationError`

```
columnNumber: 21
fileName: "http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js line 47 > eval"
lineNumber: 16
message: "Access token is required for new ApiAi.Client instance"
name: "ApiAiClientConfigurationError"
ngDebugContext: Object { view: {…}, nodeIndex: 1, nodeDef: {…}, … }
ngErrorLogger: function bound ()
stack: "ApiAiBaseError@webpack-internal:///../../../../api-ai-javascript/ts/Errors.ts:18:23\nApiAiClientConfigurationError@webpack-internal:///../../../../api-ai-javascript/ts/Errors.ts:27:21\nApiAiClient@webpack-internal:///../../../../api-ai-javascript/ts/ApiAiClient.ts:16:19\nChatService@webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/chat/chat.service.ts:23:23\n_createClass@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11110:20\n_createProviderInstance$1@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11086:26\nresolveNgModuleDep@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11071:17\nNgModuleRef_.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12307:16\nresolveDep@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12805:12\ncreateClass@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12667:29\ncreateDirectiveInstance@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12512:37\ncreateViewNodes@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13973:53\ncallViewAction@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14407:13\nexecComponentViewsAction@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14316:13\ncreateViewNodes@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14001:5\ncreateRootView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13862:5\ncallWithDebugContext@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:15287:39\ndebugCreateRootView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14570:12
```

How do I **correctly** add my Dialog Flow's  access token in the environments folder?

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]**
I read from this source and got all the info I needed.

https://alligator.io/angular/environment-variables/